# Confusing layer order of overlapping divs with content and background colors

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo">howdy howdy howdy how</div>
<div class="bar">Hello</div>​
```

and the following CSS:

```
.foo {
    background-color:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:.75em;
}

.bar {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The layer order is something like this:

[image: weird layer order]

Here's the associated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3J8D/

I would expect the red background to be on top of the black text and don't understand why the black text is on top of the red background.

I can fix this problem using `position: relative`, but I'm just curious.

**Why is the black text on top of the red background?**

I'm particularly looking for an official source/standard that explains this behaviour.

Comment: Happens in Chrome, but not in Firefox. But no idea why.

Comment: Somewhat similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue

Comment: @bfavaretto: I'm seeing it consistently across the latest versions of all browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock Now I am too. I probably pasted an updated, `/2` jsfiddle url (with `position:relative`) into Firefox. Oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to understand it, even after reading [the](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) multiple times, and [BoltClock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11088328/825789) to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue).

But it seems the explanation is simple: since these are two static (i.e. non-positioned), block-level elements inside the **same stacking context** (the root context), they are drawn in the following order:

- background of `#foo`
- background of `#bar`
- text content of `#foo`
- text content of `#bar`

Thus, the output we see in the question.

The paint order is dictated by an algorithm described in [Appendix E](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) of the CSS 2.1 spec. What is not in the appendix (but is mentioned [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index)), is that the algorithm is applied recursively *for each stacking context* (not each *element*).

Comment: The root stacking context is `html`, not `body`. Besides that, you basically got it. Nicely done :)

Comment: @BoltClock So the `body` is creating a new stacking context too? I thought not. BTW: sorry if I wasted your time asking for help. I got somewhat obsessed about this question. The last sentence in my answer explains the source of all my confusion.

Comment: `body` doesn't create a new stacking context, but as a child of `html`, it's painted on top of `html`, followed by the two `div`s. I suppose that comment was for clarification for the OP and other readers, more than anything. And no worries, no time wasted - I figured you were working on it anyway.

Comment: Also note that the "text content" is represented as anonymous inline boxes with respect to the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got lost: step `7.2.1.4.1.1` :). And thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew the paint order is so complicated. This seems really counterintuitive to me - can you think of an example where this behaviour is more intuitive than the behaviour I was expecting?

Comment: @JamieWong I agree it's not intuitive. Maybe they defined it this way based on the "normal" flow of elements, where they never overlap - unless they are positioned, in which case the paint order is different (as you noticed when you added `position: relative`). Negative margins are basically a hack - often necessary to create cross-browser CSS layouts, and perhaps they weren't paying much attention to that when the paint order algorithm was created. Who knows?

Comment: Negative margins aren't a hack *per se*, but I wouldn't blame the working group for overlooking them while working on the painting algorithm :)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index

> "This example demonstrates the notion of transparency. The default behavior of the background is to allow boxes behind it to be visible. In the example, each box transparently overlays the boxes below it. This behavior can be overridden by using one of the existing background properties"

Comment: ... which are used on the example code. No transparency here.