# Why does z-index: -1; appear above z-index: 1;?

Tags: css, z-index

Explain this behavior:

```
<div style="z-index: 1"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
   position: relative;
   background: red;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;    
}

div:before {
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2VexH/2/

Only difference is the first div has z-index: 1 set.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Setting a positioned element's [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) to anything other than `auto` (the initial value) causes the element to generate a new stacking context for its descendant boxes.

This prevents any of its descendants from appearing below it, including the `div:before` pseudo-element, *even if their `z-index` is negative*. Of course, any descendant with a negative `z-index` will continue to appear below a descendant with a zero or positive `z-index` within the containing element, but that containing element will always be at the very back.<sup>1</sup>

The rest of your `div` elements that don't have a `z-index` set will use the initial value instead, and therefore not generate stacking contexts for their pseudo-elements, allowing the pseudo-elements to appear below the real elements. The stacking context in which they are drawn instead is that of `body`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that the *content* of a stacking context root will still appear above the *background* of a descendant with a negative `z-index`. This is intentional, and is covered in greater detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue/11088328#11088328), with relevant links to the spec.</sub>