# :after : z-index doesn't work

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

I'd like to put the black rectangle (:after) behind the h2, but z-index doesn't work.

I have this code in html

```
  <h2>Ce que tu auras peut-être un jour ou l'autre...</h2>
```

and this in CSS :

```css
#general .page h2 {
position: relative;
text-indent: -9999px;
width: 718px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
height: 116px;
z-index: 10;
background: url(img/banniere-hi-04.png);
}

#general .page h2:after {
display: block;
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
left: 658px;
width: 544px;
height: 72px;
z-index: -1;
background: black;
}
```

Here's the problem (here with a black rectangle) : 
http://www.robinmastromarino.be/dataviz04/

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Do pseudo-elements have position?

Comment: @isherwood: Yes, they do.

Comment: Then I'm no help at all. :-)

Comment: What do you need help with?

Comment: @BoltClock I'd like to put the black rectangle (:after) behind the h2.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/z-index-of-before-or-after-to-be-below-the-element-is-that-possible?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give `<div class="page">` a relative position and a positive z-index, then remove the z-index on the `<h2>` as the pseudo-element creates a new stacking context

[More info as to why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context)

---

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give a child node a lower z-index than it's parent.

Comment: Only if the parent forms a new stacking context (which in this case it does because of `z-index: 10`).

Comment: Sure you can, it just makes the child fall below its parent.

Comment: You're right in this case, but as explained in my comment it only holds true in certain cases. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712040/why-does-z-index-1-appear-above-z-index-1/11712096#11712096) for a more detailed explanation. (cc @cimmanon)

Comment: Well, I said "a lower z-inxex than it's parent" which means not `auto`. ;-) But of course you are right. Nevermind.