# z-Index behaviour on pseudo elements

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

see:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kq2PY/

the div is relative with z-index 5, and the :after thing is absolute with z-index 2.

So shouldn't :after be behind the div?

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
}    

div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;            /*  <= not working:( */
    background: #3d3;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px; 
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>erferf</div>
```

Comment: Interestingly, if you set it to a negative number it displays behind the text but in front of the div background :/

Comment: @Chris Francis: [There's a Stack Overflow question for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue)

Comment: @BoltClock great reference, thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You would have to give pseudo elements a negative z-index to get it to go behind it's parent, plus remove the z-index on the parent.
http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/Kq2PY/4/

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    background: #000;
    padding: 10px;
}    

div:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;            /*  <= not working:( */
    background: #3d3;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px; 
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>erferf</div>
```

Comment: @Alex: It's normal behavior, but it's mostly explained by the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) and all it offers is a very technical breakdown of what's going on...

Comment: I don't think it's a bug because that's how it displays on the browsers I've tested(IE9, Opera, Chrome, FF). It is pretty absurd though.

Comment: Removing the Z-index of the parent as answered above is important, otherwise the z-index on the pseudo elements wont work as desired.

Comment: Somehow does not work 100% for fixed positioned parent.. it is just behind text, but not behind element itself. :/ http://jsfiddle.net/jklm313/Kq2PY/4/

Comment: Removing the z-index on the parent element is important as said above, as well as any other property that can create a stacking context such as transform, filter etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
div { z-index: 1; }

div::after { z-index: -1;}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: So a problem I encountered was that with `::before` on an element that was being used for a background image caused all the children (that were inside of the background image container tag) to be drawn underneath the image (that had a low opacity), so I could see the buttons I wanted to click, but couldn't, because it was really just clicking the background image. When you put `z-index: -1;` on just the pseudo element, it hides the image, but when you add `z-index: 1;` to the parent, it displays both... beats me with a stick.