# Pseudo element on parent hidden behind child image on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

Why in IE8, is the background color of a pesudo element flowing behind children of the parent? The text flows in front, but the background-color does not. Z-index did not seem to help any.

I haven't been able to determine if this is a bug in IE8 or not. It seems like this would have been a pretty common use-case, but I couldn't find many blog posts or SO questions related to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/VAg2E/

```
    <div id="parent">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>


    #parent{ padding: 20px; }
    #parent:before{
       content: 'Behind the image';
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;   
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       background-color: red;
    }
```

Edit : [A related Stack Overflow Question about Stacking Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue/11088328#11088328)

Comment: Hi Robert, did you ever find a work around for this problem?

Comment: I honestly don't remember -- but I don't think I did

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in IE8; since your `:before` pseudo-element is positioned, it should create a new stacking context and always be drawn on top of the `img` [unless you give it a negative `z-index`](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/VAg2E/2) (even then, the entire element should be drawn behind it, not just its background).

This issue also seems specific to stacking between `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements and replaced elements like `img`. It looks like IE8 is treating replaced content differently in terms of stacking, but whatever it is doing, it's definitely not conforming to the spec.

As you're probably aware, this is fixed in IE9.

Comment: It just seems really strange that the text would render in front, and only the background behind.

Comment: @Robert: I think IE is treating the image as a background of a descendant inline box, and the absolutely-positioned pseudo-element as an inline element in the same stacking context, subjecting them to [some pretty counter-intuitive stacking rules that only start to make sense after closer examination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue/11088328#11088328)... except it's applying those rules completely wrongly.

Comment: If I understand that link, and IE8 is painting the image as a background layer, then using :after should paint the background in front of the image but alas, it's still behind.

Comment: Bummer - This answer explains the root of the problem, so I'm going to accept it as the answer, but I'm hoping somewhere there is a workaround that will solve the problem too. Hopefully!

Answer (score 2):

Have your exact same issue, the only thing you can do is force the stacking order via CSS and `z-index`. The only catch is that `z-index` is placed on child element starting from parent element, so you wont be able to do a proper logic order as `#parent-element {z-index: 2}` and `#child-element {z-index: 1}`, the `z-index` for the `#child-element` will just be set to level 1 as a separate stack order *inside* the `#parent-element`.

You can still set `z-index` for the `#child-element` with a -1 value, it will just get back the whole `#parent-element` stacking order.

So to recap:

```
#parent-element { z-index: 99;} /* or any arbitrary number fitting */
#child-element {z-index: -1;}
```

Also remember to give both elements a `position: relative/absolute` to enable the stacking order fo `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

IE8 only supports pseudos if `<!DOCTYPE>` is declared.   [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
    #parent { padding: 20px; z-index: 2; }
    #parent:before {
       content: 'Behind the image';
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;   
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       background-color: red;
       z-index: -1;
    }​
```

Comment: Although correct, it's not the issue described here, the Doctype is declared in the jsFiddle (and in the site I'm working on), and the pseudo element renders, but the background of the pseudo element flows behind children images.

Comment: Changing `position: absolute` to `position: relative` seems to have fixed it.

Comment: With position: relative; it renders the element in front, but it still remains part of the layout flow.

Comment: What does `z-index` have to do with the doctype?