# z-index when using ::after under element

Tags: css, z-index, pseudo-element

If we use `z-index` combined with `position: absolute;` its possible to place the `::before` of a element under itself. There is a good example on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3032856/2256325) ([jsfiddle.net/Ldtfpvxy](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldtfpvxy/)).

Basically

```
<div id="element"></div>

#element { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#element::after {
    content: "";
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;

    /* create a new stacking context */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;  /* to be below the parent element */
}
```

renders:

[image]

So the stacking context/order is defined by `z-index`. But when I apply `z-index: 1;` to the element and `z-index: -1;` to its `::before` I cannot achieve the same thing.

Only if I omit `z-index` from the element.

Any ideas why this is? Is the element rendered after its `::before` & `::after` pseudos so they get the same `z-index`?

**Working:** https://jsfiddle.net/Ldtfpvxy/
**Not working:** https://jsfiddle.net/Ldtfpvxy/1/ (only added `z-index: 1;` to element)

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/z-index-of-before-or-after-to-be-below-the-element-is-that-possible), Sorry @Sergio, I haven't noticed you already linked it :)

Comment: @Keammoort i linked to that same thread in my question already because it is related. The example is from there.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of an explanation and so no adding answer but what I understood from [this article](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) is that any value for `z-index` (other than default auto) creates a new stacking context and that a child can be positioned behind its parent only when they have same stacking context. Here since both have `z-index` assigned, I assume the stacking contexts are different.

Comment: It might have something to do with generated content inheriting property:value pairs from parent elements. I would look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html

Comment: Also worth noting that the issue happens when `z-index` on parent has any value.

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue

Comment: what if my element has absolute:position and z-index:1 like here https://jsfiddle.net/x5x6ye97/1/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your div and its ::after pseudo-element are members of the same stacking context, in this case the root stacking context. The new stacking context you give the pseudo-element would be used as a reference to its children (which are non-existent), but the `z-index` value applies to the current stacking context. And the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) dictates the following paint order for each stacking context:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in
>   back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

Look, *child stacking contexts with negative stack levels*, such as your `div::after` are painted before *the positioned descendants with stack level 0*, such as the `div` itself. This explains the behavior you noticed.

Comment: Is there anything to do with the default value `z-index:auto`? As explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) `auto` - *The box does not establish a new local stacking context.*

Comment: @Pangloss If the div established a new stacking context, then it would not be possible to position any of its children below it. So in this case, yes, the absence of an explicit `z-index` in the div is part of the explanation. But remember that `z-index` alone does not create stacking contexts; they depend on the combination of `z-index` and `position` (or `opacity`).

Comment: If there is a div set to `position:relative;` and `z-index:0;` (other than *none* or `auto`), so the simple fact is - no matter what any children can never go below it, is that true?

Comment: @bfavaretto Of course, `z-index` alone does not do *anything*, let alone not create stacking contexts.

Comment: @Pangloss AFAIK yes, that's true for children that create stacking contexts themselves.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this:

Comment: (Accidentally hit enter) In the current example, if only the `::after` has a z-index, the body is rendered at Step 1. The `::after` is rendered at step 2, because it is a child stacking context of the body. The `<div>` is rendered at either step 3 if it is set to `position:static`, but at step 6 if it has an explicit position value. When you add the `z-index: 1` to the `<div>`, it is still rendered at step 6, because it is now a child stacking context of the `<body>`. The `::after`, however, is rendered as step 2 of its parent's rendering process, instead of step 2 of the body's.

Comment: @Deimyts Exactly. You explained way better than I did.

Answer (score 6):

Specifying `z-index` you are creating a new stacking content;

if this is done only on the child `::after` pseudo-elem the parent won't establish a new stacking content and everything will work as expected.

But adding `z-index` on the parent element will start a new stack (which will also wrap the child-stack..).
And if you look at the first 2 points on [stack rendering specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers) you'll see background will be rendered before other child-stacks:

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the **background** and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the **child stacking contexts** with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. ... ...

[here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/Ldtfpvxy/59/), to clarify the different rendering behavior for nested stacking background.

---

`position: relative` **is not optional**; with the default `position:static`, `z-index` has no effect.