# lighten background color on hover for different background colors

Tags: css

I have multiple elements, their background colors are different from each other. like:

```
<div class="element"> Content of the DIV</div>
<div class="element2"> Content of the DIV</div>

.element{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#888888;
}
.element2{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#222222;
}
```

I want to make hover like:

```
.element:hover, .element2:hover{}
```

When I bring mouse over the element, only background should be little bit lighter. I don't want to use `opacity: 0.4` (lightens whole div) or `background-color:rgba(50,50,50,0.5);` (only for one color)

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yrg3v/6/)

Comment: Would you be ok with introducing an extra `span` element for the content like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/9x6mtvLx/). This is the simplest that I could think of. (*Edit:* The original fiddle was the wrong version. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/9x6mtvLx/3/) is the correct one.)

Comment: Also you might want to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962432/is-it-possible-to-change-only-the-alpha-of-a-rgba-background-colour-on-hover

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to achieve this is to simply apply a `background-image` to your elements on `:hover`. Either using a CSS gradient (which I generated using [ColorZilla's "Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator"](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0.5+0,0.5+100)):

```
.element:hover,
.element2:hover,
.element3:hover {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0.5+0,0.5+100 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80ffffff', endColorstr='#80ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
```

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #888888;
}
.element2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #222222;
}
.element3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
.element:hover,
.element2:hover,
.element3:hover {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+100&0.5+0,0.5+100 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80ffffff', endColorstr='#80ffffff', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Content of the DIV</div>
<div class="element2">Content of the DIV</div>
<div class="element3">Content of the DIV</div>
```

Or using a partially-transparent image:

```
.element:hover,
.element2:hover,
.element3:hover {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5udh0.png);
}
```

```css
.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #888888;
}
.element2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #222222;
}
.element3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
.element:hover,
.element2:hover,
.element3:hover {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5udh0.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">Content of the DIV</div>
<div class="element2">Content of the DIV</div>
<div class="element3">Content of the DIV</div>
```

This works because of the 'stacking' order of the background properties; the `background-color` sits at the back and the `background-image` sits 'above' that layer.

References:

- "[Using CSS Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_gradients)," at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: I like this approach a lot as it doesn't need any extra elements (real or pseudo). Nicely done :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrg3v/7/) and you should wrap your content into divs so you can apply `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)` to them:

```css
.element{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#888888;
    position:relative;
}
.element2{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#222222;
    position:relative;
}
.element:hover > div, .element2:hover > div{
    /* what can we put here? */
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="element"><div>Content of the DIV</div></div>
<div class="element2"><div>Content of the DIV</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a trick that uses the way stacking contents are rendered, backgrounds always below contents (even if it belongs to a higher stack):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/Lvhcpnun/)

```css
  div {
      width:100px;
      height:50px;
      z-index:2;
      position:relative;
  }
  .element {
      background-color:#888888;
  }
  .element2 {
      background-color:red;
  }
  .element3 {
      background-color:cyan;
  }
  div:hover:after {
      content:'';
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background:white;
      opacity:0.5;
      z-index:-2;
  }
```

```html
<div class="element">test</div>
<div class="element2">test</div>
<div class="element3">test</div>
```

if you're interested in the explanation check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322958/z-index-when-using-after-under-element/31671977#31671977)

Answer (score 0):

```
OR YOU CAN TRY THIS CODE ALSO
OR YOU CAN TRY THIS ONE ALSO::

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.element{
width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#888888;
}
.element:hover {
    background-color: yellow;

}
.element2{
width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#222222;

}

.element2:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="element">

  Content of the DIV

</div>
<div class="element2">
Content of the Div2
</div>


</body>
</html>
```