# Stacking context for position: fixed pseudo-elements

Tags: css, cross-browser, background-image, css-position, z-index

I'm trying to implement fixed background images through the code described in [this post from Four Kitchens](https://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/fix-scrolling-performance-css-will-change-property), but with multiple background images rather than just one. This is the code from the post:

```
.what-we-do-cards {
  @include clearfix;
  border-top: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .46);
  color: $white;
  padding-bottom: 4em;
  overflow: hidden; // added for pseudo-element
  position: relative; // added for pseudo-element

  // Fixed-position background image
  &::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: fixed; // instead of background-attachment
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    background: url('/img/front/strategy.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    will-change: transform; // creates a new paint layer
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

The basic idea is to create sections of content with the `:before` pseudo-element for fixed-position background images, except the example linked to in the post only uses a single fixed position section.

I have a troubleshooting [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v127Ljwh/) that works in Safari and Chrome, but not Firefox, and I'm trying to figure out how the browsers are handling the pseudo-elements differently. Also, if you comment out `will-change: transform;` in Chrome (line 25), you'll see the same behavior as Firefox, which I believe is due to [Chrome triggering a stacking context](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera/pull/330). I'm not sure why Safari works without the stacking context triggered in Chrome.

There's a good SO answer regarding stacking context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue), but I'm not sure how it works with fixed position elements, pseudo-elements, and explicitly setting z-index.

EDIT: The original jsfiddle showed how a containing box for fixed elements was created (or not) across browsers, but didn't really show how background-images change. @Oriol explained how adding `transform: rotate(0);` forces the creation of a containing box on Firefox, but it also removes the fixed-in-relation-to-the-viewport effect in Chrome. I've created a [new jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ng021n4c/) - what's causing the differences in rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that `will-change: transform` produces a stacking context. However, stacking contexts are unrelated to this issue. In fact, the CSS working group recently [resolved](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jul/0032.html) that `position: fixed` already creates a stacking context.

Instead, this is due to the creation of a containing block for fixed-position elements.

According to [The `will-change` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change/#valuedef-custom-ident),

> If any non-initial value of a property would cause the element to
>   generate a containing block for fixed-position elements, specifying
>   that property in [`will-change`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change/#propdef-will-change) must cause the element to generate
>   a containing block for fixed-position elements.

Therefore, `will-change: transform` produces a containing block for fixed-position elements, because according to [The Transform Rendering Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-rendering),

> Any value other than `none` for the transform results in the creation
>   of both a stacking context and a containing block. The object acts as
>   a containing block for fixed positioned descendants.

I think Safari does not need `will-change: transform` because it believes that fixed elements should create a containing block for fixed descendants, even if that isn't standard. That wouldn't be strange, because fixed elements produced a stacking context on Webkit browsers before the CSSWG resolved to do so.

And Firefox supports `will-change`, but it hasn't implemented this behavior yet. However, you can achieve the same result by setting `transform` to anything but `none`, e.g.

```css
.fixed { transform: rotate(0); }
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
.fixed {
  height: 20vh;
  transform: rotate(0); /* Containing block for fixed elements */
}
.fixed:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.one:before { background: orange; }
.two:before { background: blue; }
.three:before { background: black; }
.four:before { background: gray; }
.five:before { background: purple; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one fixed"></div>
  <div class="two fixed"></div>
  <div class="three fixed"></div>
  <div class="four fixed"></div>
  <div class="five fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does this account for the different rendering in Firefox? And why does Safari seem to create a containing block despite lack of support for will-change? http://caniuse.com/#feat=will-change

Comment: @nicolekanderson I meant that Firefox hasn't implemented that setting `will-change` to something which can create a containing block for fixed elements must create it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the clarification! I don't suppose you have a fix for IE as well? :)

Comment: @nicolekanderson If IE supports `transform` properly, the Firefox solution should also work. But I don't have IE at hand to test it.

Comment: I've created an updated jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wgt917aq/) and tested via Browserstack, no such luck in IE.