# pseudo-element stacking for animations

Tags: css, animation, pseudo-element

I have a ripple effect set to a CSS class using a pseudo selector.
I'd like that animation to run from behind the element itself, but I can't manage to find how to do so.

```css
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: lightblue;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
}
i.ripple:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: darkorange;
 animation: ripple 2s ease-in infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple {
 0% {transform: scale(1);opacity: .5;}
 100% {transform: scale(8);opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<i class="ripple button">test</i>
```

If you run the example, you will see that the orange circle is on top of the blue box from the .button class, I'd like it to be behind.

I think this issue is related to this other question:
[::before pseudo-element stacking order issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088176/before-pseudo-element-stacking-order-issue) 
But can't figure out much of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set its `z-index` to `-1` and you should be good.

```css
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: lightblue;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
}
i.ripple:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: darkorange;
 animation: ripple 2s ease-in infinite;

 z-index:-1;
}
@keyframes ripple {
 0% {transform: scale(1);opacity: .5;}
 100% {transform: scale(8);opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<i class="ripple button">test</i>
```

Comment: hm, it does work, but my button class has a z-index: 1; (not in the example, that's my fault) and seems to be messing with this solution

Comment: @Dunnow this is impossible with this html structure. You would have to add an element inside the `.button` to contain the text and set the background etc so that the pseudo element can go behind it. Since the button creates a stacking order (*by being positioned and having a z-index no child of it can go behind it, and pseudo-elements are child elements*)

Comment: Okay, I'll try to eliminate the z-index: 1 from my code to then apply the -1 to the ripple itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Z-Index.

```css
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: lightblue;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
}
i.ripple:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: darkorange;
 animation: ripple 2s ease-in infinite;
  z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes ripple {
 0% {transform: scale(1);opacity: .5;}
 100% {transform: scale(8);opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<i class="ripple button">test</i>
```

```css
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background: lightblue;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
}
i.ripple:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: darkorange;
 animation: ripple 2s ease-in infinite;
}
@keyframes ripple {
 0% {transform: scale(1);opacity: .5;}
 100% {transform: scale(8);opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<i class="ripple button">test</i>
```